# JAXB collection mapping

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm new in dealing with XML in Java, but one of services I use returns it as result. Until now, I've dealt with mapping XML into POJO, using `@XmlRootElement`-like annotations. But now I have absolutely no idea to do with this document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<response>
    <status>
        <code>0</code>
    </status>
    <result>
        <limit>2</limit>
        ...

        <data>
            <row0>
                <ID>85427</ID>
                <name>Default</name>
                <siteID>40628</siteID>
                 ... some elements
            </row0>
        </data>
    </result>
</response>
```

Until now, I used these classes to bind XML (except 'data' node) into POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
public class Response {

    private Status status;

    private String result;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @XmlElement(name ="result")
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}



@XmlRootElement(name = "status")
public class Status {

    private String ID;
    private String code;
    private String error;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "code")
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "error")
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

But now I need to bind  content as collection of elements. I've looked for examples, and everywhere people use specific tag to define root element for collection's item, but in this document, root tags will be as `<row0>`, `<row1>` etc.

I use Jackson, which, if I understand correctly, uses JAXB annotations to define XML to POJO bind rules. So could this deal be solved this way, or I have to manipulate this document in DOM-style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using something like this :

Create your Row class that represents your `<row0>,<row1>` etc... and map it with JAXB like you would do it normally.

Then create a class that extends `XmlAdapter<List<Row>,List<Element>>` and define the abstracts methods marshall and unmarshall.

Here is some Javadoc to help you :

XmlAdapter : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

Element : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

Then create a Data class :

```
public class Data{

    private List<Row> rows;

    public List<Row> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyRowsAdapter.class)
    public void setRows(List<Row> result) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

}
```

Then you can add this mapping to your Response class :

```
private Data data;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

@XmlElement(name="data")
public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Note that for this solution to work, your `<data>` element must only contains elements like your Row.

Also, you cannot use @XmlElementWrapper instead of using a Data class because of a bug in JAXB which make incompatible @XmlElementWrapper and @XmlJavaTypeAdapter : https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-787

Comment: I did what you advised, but my adapter's marshall & unmarshall methods haven't been called. 
I haven't even implemented marshall & unmarshall logic, just wrote return null and placed breakpoint within them to be sure that they're called.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't aware of a bug in JAXB, i corrected my answer and added at the end why my precedent answer didn't work.

Comment: I've edited my classes as you advised, here are the sources: [Response](http://pastebin.com/qVhMG4QB), [Data](http://pastebin.com/ZmFGWeV6) and [Adapter](http://pastebin.com/0SzSf3wf). Data = null. I've tried to switch Row & Element generic types in my adapter, but there wasn't result. Maybe Adapter isn't currect? Btw, in my tests, I invoke with this code: JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml), Response.class). Could it be the reason of failure?

Comment: I mean, I tried to put some another classes in my Adapter to produce exception or some error.

Comment: There is a discordance in your mapping. Your XML have your Data element inside your Result element, and your code have your Result element represented as String and your Data Object is outside the result element. Which of the two is correct ? Sorry i didn't see it earlier BTW.

Comment: To clarify, with your current XML (the one that you provided in your question) , you should have a Result class that contains a the Data object.

Comment: Right, your adjustments gave results, [Result](http://pastebin.com/DBAN9kzp) class binds simple elements like "limit", but Data is still not bound. Did I forgot something else?

Comment: Try adding \@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY) on your Data class. Also, when unmarshalling, is it your data object or the List inside the data object that is null ?

Comment: List inside Data is null.
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY) - no result. Adapter methods still haven't been called.

Comment: It seems that Jackson does not understands some JAXB Annotation, including \@XmlAnyElement, see : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations. I can't think of a solution to your problem using jackson.

Comment: I think it'll work with JAXB reference implementation. If it doesn't, tell me. And if you still want to use jackson, please tell me so that i can retract my answer.

Comment: I have to leave this issue for some time, we've implementer required functionality in other way, but I have strong intention to solve this task after few days, If you don't consider that as waste your time.

Comment: Absolutely not, please comment again when you can focus on this problem again, i'll provide my humble help :) . I'll update my answer to reflect what we reached just in case someone with a solution to your problem happens to see this post.

Comment: I quit my last job when I had to solve this problem so I don't to process xml anymore. Thank you for your efforts, I'll mar your answer as correct.